# Where can we find a list of all available BibTeX entries (and the available fields for each of them)?

Tags: bibtex, big-list

Would be very useful if we have a list of all available BibTeX entries with all possible fields for each of them.

Something like this one:

```
@book{alias,
 author    = "Complete Author Name",
 title     = "Complete Title",
 publisher = "Complete Publisher Name",
 year      =  [year],
 address   = "Complete address",
 edition   = "Complete edition information"
}
```

([year], in this case, should be replaced by something like 2015, for example)

Where can we find it?

Comment: This may not be complete as custom fields can be created, the documentation for JabRef has an excellent discussion on fields.  Go to http://jabref.sourceforge.net/help/Contents.php and check documentation and open the Language version you prefer.  (As an aside, when I taught "Technical Writing using LaTeX", I would have all the students install and use JabRef to create and manage bibtex entries.

Comment: And for those using `biblatex`, there are additional standard entries... as well as further styles with custom ones and the possibility of adding your own. This question is a little bit like asking for a list of all possible LaTeX macros...

Answer (score 9):

`texdoc bibtex` is the obvious source. This lists all standard types with their required and optional fields (pp. 8-9):

> **article** An article from a journal or magazine. Required fields:
>   author, title, journal, year. Optional fields: volume, number, pages,
>   month, note.
>
> **book** A book with an explicit publisher. Required fields:
>   author or editor, title, publisher, year. Optional fields: volume or
>   number, series, address, edition, month, note.
>
> **booklet** A work that is
>   printed and bound, but without a named publisher or sponsoring
>   institution. Required field: title. Optional fields: author,
>   howpublished, address, month, year, note.
>
> **conference** The same as
>   INPROCEEDINGS, included for Scribe compatibility.
>
> **inbook** A part of a
>   book, which may be a chapter (or section or whatever) and/or a range
>   of pages. Required fields: author or editor, title, chapter and/or
>   pages, publisher, year. Optional fields: volume or number, series,
>   type, address, edition, month, note.
>
> **incollection** A part of a book
>   having its own title. Required fields: author, title, booktitle,
>   publisher, year. Optional fields: editor, volume or number, series,
>   type, chapter, pages, address, edition, month, note.
>
> **inproceedings** An
>   article in a conference proceedings. Required fields: author, title,
>   booktitle, year. Optional fields: editor, volume or number, series,
>   pages, address, month, organization, publisher, note.
>
> **manual** Technical
>   documentation. Required field: title. Optional fields: author,
>   organization, address, edition, month, year, note.
>
> **mastersthesis** A
>   Master’s thesis. Required fields: author, title, school, year.
>   Optional fields: type, address, month, note.
>
> **misc** Use this type when
>   nothing else fits. Required fields: none. Optional fields: author,
>   title, howpublished, month, year, note.
>
> **phdthesis** A PhD thesis.
>   Required fields: author, title, school, year. Optional fields: type,
>   address, month, note.
>
> **proceedings** The proceedings of a conference.
>   Required fields: title, year.
>   Optional fields: editor, volume or number, series, address, month,
>   organization, publisher, note.
>
> **techreport** A report published by a
>   school or other institution, usually numbered within a series.
>   Required fields: author, title, institution, year. Optional fields:
>   type, number, address, month, note.
>
> **unpublished** A document having an
>   author and title, but not formally published. Required fields:
>   author, title, note. Optional fields: month, year.

Plus all entries support the `key` field.

Note that `biblatex` treats certain fields differently from `bibtex`, notably the `@inbook` type. It also has a lot of additional fields.

And, of course, `bibtex` and `biblatex` styles further extend things, no matter which one you are using.

Answer (score 1):

@cfr has provided a list of entry types recognized by BibTeX, along with lists of required and optional field types for each entry typle -- as given by the "basic" bibliography styles -- `plain`, `abbrv`, and `alpha`.

The fields, and what BibTeX is supposed to with any given field, are defined by the bibliography style you select. For example, the **plain** bibliography style defines the following fields:

> address author booktitle chapter edition editor howpublished institution journal key month note number organization pages publisher school series title type volume year

Other bibliography styles can define additional fields. For instance, the **apacite** bibliography style defines

> address annote annotate author booktitle chair chapter day doi edition editor englishtitle firstkey howpublished institution journal key lastchecked month nihms note number organization originaladdress originalbooktitle originaledition originaleditor originaljournal originalnumber originalpages originalpublisher originalvolume originalyear pages pmcid publisher school series symposium text title translator type url urldate volume year

You'll need to read the documentation that goes with a given bibliography style to learn which fields are either required or optional for a given entry typle. (Fields that are neither required nor optional are ignored.)